# Quickblox cordova sample video webrtc app don't show camera stream on android device

Tags: android, cordova, webrtc, quickblox

I tried a Cordova sample app for video calling from Quickblox. I have used the code from Quickblox http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-cordova.

I used android phone with (lollipop android-5.0) for testing. When video call is made to other I don't see video stream from my mobile phone. I can see other video played into the app. When I call to or receive from other, my video panel where my camera stream shown turns into black. But don't see video captured locally or on other devices.

Same code run on laptop firefox browser very well. I can see all video streams from me and others provided they originated from browser devices and not android devices.

[screenshot of mobile app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERlCq.png)

Answer (score 0):

On Android you need to request permission to access the video stream. This is done either in your config.xml or in a plugin file.

This code block is from a plugin I am using, in plugin.xml:

In Marshmallow onwards you need to ask for permission at run time *instead*, but to provide compatibility you will need to do both.

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to
>   apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. This
>   approach streamlines the app install process, since the user does not
>   need to grant permissions when they install or update the app. It also
>   gives the user more control over the app's functionality; for example,
>   a user could choose to give a camera app access to the camera but not
>   to the device location. The user can revoke the permissions at any
>   time, by going to the app's Settings screen.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0):

Check for permissions. I had the same issue. Try giving permissions manually to the application on phone.